# smoosh 4 similar methods into 1 method

Tags: android

finishing up an android app, I have four methods each pertaining to their respective buttons. each is a color. if one is pressed, and its the correct color being told to be pressed it gets a +point, else it gets a -point.

these are the 4 methods im trying to combine into one, though I am having trouble figuring out that if i did, then I wouldnt have a way to to assign negative points. I was thinking that if i did like if blue, add points, else if teal add points etc... but this approach takes away from the fact that if they were told to press blue and pressed teal then it wouldnt register to add a -point.

here is the code:

```
public void blue_pressed(View view) {
    correct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.right);
    incorrect = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wrong);
    if (count != 0 && !(count >NUMBER_ROUNDS) && color == blue) {
        cor++;
        correct.setText(getString(R.string.num_cor, cor));
    } else {
        inc++;
        incorrect.setText(getString(R.string.num_inc, inc));
    }
    start_pressed(view);
}

public void teal_pressed(View view) {
    correct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.right);
    incorrect = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wrong);
    if (count != 0 && !(count > NUMBER_ROUNDS) && color == teal) {
        cor++;
        correct.setText(getString(R.string.num_cor, cor));
    } else {
        inc++;
        incorrect.setText(getString(R.string.num_inc, inc));
    }
    start_pressed(view);
}

public void purp_pressed(View view) {
    correct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.right);
    incorrect = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wrong);
    if (count != 0 && !(count > NUMBER_ROUNDS) && color == purp) {
        cor++;
        correct.setText(getString(R.string.num_cor, cor));
    } else {
        inc++;
        incorrect.setText(getString(R.string.num_inc, inc));
    }
    start_pressed(view);
}


public void pink_pressed(View view) {
    correct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.right);
    incorrect = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wrong);
    if (count != 0 && !(count > NUMBER_ROUNDS) && color == pink) {
        cor++;
        correct.setText(getString(R.string.num_cor, cor));
    } else {
        inc++;
        incorrect.setText(getString(R.string.num_inc, inc));
    }
    start_pressed(view);
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is really more about refactoring than Android.

You have 4 methods that differ only regarding the colour in the if statement. This means if you pass in the colour as a parameter, you would have only one method instead, and maintain only that. But you cannot change the signature of the "onClick" methods, so what to do? You create an additional private helper method that you call in all your four "onClick" methods.

In Eclipse you can extract easily the body of one of the "onClick" methods and refactor it into your helper method. Enter the shortcut: alt+command+M. Then change the signature of the extracted method manually to include an int parameter to compare `color` to. Finally you get...

```
private void buttonPressed(View view, int col){
    correct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.right);
    incorrect = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wrong);
    if (count != 0 && !(count >NUMBER_ROUNDS) && color == col) {
        cor++;
        correct.setText(getString(R.string.num_cor, cor));
    } else {
        inc++;
        incorrect.setText(getString(R.string.num_inc, inc));
    }
    start_pressed(view);
}

public void blue_pressed(View view) {
    buttonPressed(view, blue);
}

public void teal_pressed(View view) {
    buttonPressed(view, teal);
}

public void purp_pressed(View view) {
    buttonPressed(view, purp);
}

public void pink_pressed(View view) {
    buttonPressed(view, pink);
}
```

Comment: Even better - figure out the color from the button itself. It could be either `switch (view.getId()) { case R.id.blue_button: color = blue; ...` or (which is better) - using tag `color = view.getTag()` and set each button's tag to required color.

Comment: I would not go down that way. With the switch approach you need to maintain the switch, so if you add a new colour you have to remember to check your helper method and add the colour there. In my approach, if you add a new colour you add a new "onClick" method with an explicit parameter, so you'll realise that you have to set the right colour there. Also, you can set the tag as a string from xml, but then you need to parse it. Or you can set it from code. Either way, it looks messier

Comment: cool awesome @Gil, Not ideal as its now 5 methods, but defiantly cuts down the code so thats good enough :)!

Comment: @erp well the real advantage is that if you modify something in the logic of your buttons, you need to modify only one place. This pays off lots more in the long run than having one method more ;)

Comment: thanks again, nice to have helpful people when your new to something!